# Understanding how $\sum_{k=2}^n \big( \frac{3}{2} \big)^{k-1}$ has been simplified

Tags: analysis, summation

I want to understand how this sum has been simplified:

$$\sum_{k=2}^{n} \big( \frac{3}{2} \big)^{k-1} = \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \big( \frac{3}{2} \big)^{k} = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \big( \frac{3}{2} \big)^{k}-1 $$
(Up until here I understand how the indexes have been shifted).

But how is this

$$= \frac{1-(\frac{3}{2})^n}{1-\frac{3}{2}} - 1 = -2 \cdot \big(1- \big( \frac{3}{2} \big)^n \big)- 1 =  \frac{3^n}{2^{n-1}} -3$$

Can someone explain what happened in these last $3$ steps?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Formula

Comment: Note that for $k=0$, $\left( \dfrac{2}{3} \right)^0 = 1$ in the last summation.

Comment: Just algebra. 1st to 2nd: $.../(1 - 3/2) = .../(-1/2) = -2*...$; 2nd to 3rd: $-2*(1 - (3^n/2^n)) - 1 = -2*1 + 2*(3^n/2^n) - 1 = 2*(3^n/2^n) - 3 = (3^n/2^{n - 1}) - 3$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first step is just the sum of a geometric series. We have $$1+a+a^2+\dots+a^{n-1}=\frac{a^n-1}{a-1}$$ That is easy to prove: suppose the sum is $S$. Then $aS$ is the same as $S$ except for the addition of the term $a^n$ and the deletion of the term 1, so subtracting we get the result.

The second step is that dividing by $1-\frac{3}{2}$ is the same as multiplying by $-2$.

The third step is just multiplying by $-2$ and noting that $-2-1=-3$.

Comment: I don't get it. In the geometric series the end value is $n$, but here we have $n-1$ and we don't calculate $a^n - 1$, but $1- a^n$?

Comment: The series you are trying to sum has end value $n-1$. It makes no difference whether you take $(a^n-1)/(a-1)$ or $(1-a^n)/(1-a)$.

Comment: Ahh I get it now. Thanks a lot!